# Directory .../node_modules/react-native' does not contain a Gradle build. after I upgraded Intellij Idea

Tags: react-native, intellij-idea

As I wrote in the title, after I upgraded IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)
I started to get error from IDEA which is;

[image: this is error after I open intellij idea]

What could be the reason of this ?
Thanks...